# Why are the new c++ exceptions not derived from std::logic_error?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

C++11 and C++17 added some new exception types, e.g. `bad_optional_access`, `bad_variant_access`, `bad_weak_ptr` and a few others. They all derive directly from `std::exception`. It seems to me that these are all preventable if some checking was done first, and so should be derived from `std::logic_error`.

Does anyone know why they were not defined this way?

Comment: Most errors are preventable; that seems like a broad reason to consider something a logic error.

Comment: It's too bad `std::logic_error` can be caught.  It's a shortcoming in C++.  [Bugs are not recoverable errors](http://joeduffyblog.com/2016/02/07/the-error-model/#bugs-arent-recoverable-errors).

Comment: Do you mean `std::runtime_error`, `std::logic_error`, or either? Text doesn't quite match title.

Comment: Interestingly, [std::experimental::bad_optional_access](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional/bad_optional_access) is a subtype of `std::logic_error`, but [std::bad_optional_access](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/bad_optional_access) is not. Almost like it was considered but discarded.

Comment: Possible duplicate for [bad_optional_access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60881728/1387438), but I think same reasoning matches other exceptions too.

Comment: @Eljay Catching bugs makes sense so that the application can do something useful, like for instance pop up some bug reporting UI rather than defer to the default handling of the situation by the language run-time or possibly operating system.   Logic bugs could also happen if your program exposes an interpreter. An interpreted program can have a bug which shows up as a situation in the interpreter; yet the interpreter might want to handle it in some way. For instance, if there is an interactive REPL, only abort to the top of the REPL; don't terminate the whole software image.

Comment: Please note that `*optionalVal` leads to UB and code express that none empty optional here is a bug. On other hand `optionalVal.value()` code says you are expecting that it can be empty and throwing an exception is expected, so it is not a logic error.

Comment: @Eljay -- there are reasons for catching an exception other than trying to recover, such as giving a meaningful error message or logging an error. Catching an exception doesn't mean the program has to continue; the code can rethrow it, or do its best to exit gracefully.

Comment: @Kaz @PeteBecker • Please read Joe Duffy's article, and contemplate the points he raises.  Joe was the manager working on Midori project at Microsoft, and the difference between bugs and errors was one that took many years assess and distinguish.  (For an interpreter, it'd be odd for the interpreter's language domain to represent errors in that domain by using `std::logic_error`.  There should be some sort of `engine::interpreter_error` for interpreter domain errors.)

Comment: @Eljay I didn't read the article yet, but I would point out that if you let an exception escape, you don't get stack unwinding. If you are counting on RAII to do some cleanup that doesn't happen automatically when a program exits, like deleting temporary files, you need to catch the exception. Of course, you can then rethrow it.

Comment: @Elijay My point is that the interpreter would have to **catch** the `std::logic_error` (and whatever other errors) and convert them into that `engine::interpreter_error`. This is because the interpreter can expose some primitives (written in C++) to the interpreted language, and the language can abuse those primitives. The interpreter has only two options: check for and prevent those situations, or else catch the exceptions.